Rails, trying to render a new user form with role parameters and errors
`I'm making my final project website and I have a user model with 3 roles: ngo, admin, or neither(regular user). I tried to save myself time and make it more simple by combining the 3 into 1 model, but now I'm trying to render the new user form partial depending on what their role is, and I'm having issues with the logic and error displaying.
I thought I could use query parameters, but it won't display the errors when it renders the form partial.
User Controller:
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|

  if @user.save
    UserMailer.with(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_later
    # Redirect to main view if the user is an admin
    if current_user != nil && current_user.admin?
      format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: "User was successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    # Create session and redirect to user profile if not admin
    else
      session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: "Successfully created your profile!" }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    end
  # If the user's not saved re-render the forms
  else
    if params[:q] == "ngo"
      format.html { render "form_new_ngo", status: :unprocessable_entity }
    elsif params[:q] == "user"
      format.html { render "form_new_user", status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end

end

end

Main New View:
<% if params\[:q\] == nil %\>


<%= link_to "Join as Specialist", new_user_path(q: "user"), class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
<%= link_to "Join as Business", new_user_path(q: "ngo" ), class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>

<% end %>

<% if params\[:q\] == "user" %\>
<%= render "form_new_user", user: @user %\>
<% elsif params\[:q\] == "ngo" %\>
<%= render "form_new_ngo", user: @user %\>
<% elsif params\[:q\] == "admin" && current_user != nil && current_user.admin? %\>
<%= render "form_new_admin", user: @user %\>
<% end %>

<br>


<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Back", users_path %>
<% elsif params[:q] != nil %>
  <%= link_to "Back", new_user_path %>
<% end %>


Partial form for new users:




<h1>Create a new Business!</h1>


<%= form_with model: @user do |form| %>

<% if form.object.errors.any? %>
<div class="" style="color: red">
<ul>
  <% form.object.errors.each do |error| %>
<li><%= error.full_message %></li>
<% end %\>
</ul>
</div\>
<% end %\>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <%= form.email_field :email, required: true, placeholder: "123@email.com", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= form.label "Point of contact email", class: "form-label" %>
</div>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <%= form.password_field :password, required: true, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= form.label :password, class: "form-label" %>
</div>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true, placeholder: "Password required",         class: "form-control" %>
  <%= form.label :password_confirmation, class: "form-label" %>
</div>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <%= form.hidden_field :ngo, value: true %>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
  <%= form.submit "Create Organization", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>

<% end %>

Copy and pasted changed my formatting and added slashes for some reason, so I hope it's not hard to understand.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you have to render the whole template again, not just the form partial. btw, in controllers to render a partial you have to render partial: "form_new_ngo"

How do I render the whole template again? render template: "form..."? Also in the guides it says Rails does this automatically with the render method so I'm confused. Please clarify, thanks!
